# Excel VBA Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

In the line `If infl > (fc - WC(j)) * dz(j) Then` I keep getting the error "Type Mismatch" and it highlights the `-` in the line. I do now know what would cause this error?

```
Option Explicit

Dim dz() As Double
Dim WC() As Double
Dim fc() As Double
Dim NL, i As Integer

Dim sumdrain As Double
Dim infl As Double

Sub infilt()
  Dim j As Integer
  j = 1

  While (infl > 0) And (j <= NL)
    If infl > (fc - WC(j)) * dz(j) Then
      infl = infl - (fc - WC(j)) * dz(j)
      WC(j) = fc
    Else
      WC(j) = WC(j) + infl / dz(j): infl = 0
    End If
    j = j + 1
  Wend

  If infl > 0 Then
    sumdrain = sumdrain + infl
    infl = 0
  End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fc` is an array. You can't substract from it. You probably meant `fc(something)`.

Comment: fc is an array, but I would like to subtract from individual numbers within the array, one by one. Do you have any suggestions on how I would modify the code?

Comment: yep...looks like a typo...you might consider expanding the names of your vars (except the iterators) to make it easier to see that kind of mistake

Comment: if I replace all fc with fc(i) I no longer get the error. thanks

Comment: @user1977802 - there are a few ways to skin that puppy (not that I skin puppies).  A secondary for loop is easiest in your case (with some function calls to break it up), but you could also simplify the above by keeping track of the total of fc and the total subtracted value...since you don't modify fc above...